# Has TFS 2012 gitignore analog?

Tags: tfs, gitignore

I want to ignore some files when check in.
Has TFS 2012 this functionality?
Is it Exclude options?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is a .tfsignore option, but I don't know enough about it to tell you if it exactly matches the behaviors possible with gitignore. Try searching on tfsignore to see if it will do what you need.

If it is a permanent global filter that you want, you have sone control over filters in the global source control settings for your collection.